# importing @microsoft/office-js fails in react js, how do i fix this?

Tags: reactjs, npm, office-js

This installation results to module not found even though its available in my node modules directory and package.json file

```
import * as Office from '@microsoft/office-js
```

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "kazy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/office-js": "^1.1.84",
    "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "docx-to-pdf": "^1.1.0",
    "docx-to-pdf-converter": "0.0.6",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.34.3",
    "google-fonts": "^1.0.0",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "pizzip": "^3.1.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-pdf": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.76.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

I tried installing office-js for my react web application it installs fine but trying to import it does not work it results to module not found error unlike office-js-helper which works

Comment: I'm getting the same type of error. Did you have any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0):

`@microsoft/office-js` can't be imported like a regular NPM package:

Installing the NPM package locally creates a set of static Office.js files in the node_modules@microsoft\office-js\dist folder of the directory where you ran the npm install command. To use the NPM package, do the following:

1. Either manually or as part of a build script (e.g., CopyWebpackPlugin if you're using Webpack) have the files served from a destination of your choosing (e.g., from the /assets/office-js/ directory of your web
2. Reference that location in a  tag within the HTML file in your add-in project.

For example, if you add the contents of the dist folder to the assets/office-js directory of your project, then you'd add the following  tag to your HTML file:

```
<script src="/assets/office-js/office.js"></script>
```

[Source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js)

In addition, using the NPM package has disadvantages because it is out of date. So, you should use the CDN version included in the source I provided.